# Is there a system call to find if a certain path is a regular file or a hard link in unix

Tags: unix, operating-system, system-calls

If two paths have the same inode number; one of them is a hard link. Do we have a system call to know which one of them is a hard link. Or any other programatic way in C.

Comment: If two paths have the same inode number, both of them are hard links.  An entry in a directory that refers to a file is a hard link to that file.

Comment: The stat structure contains a link count (st_nlink).   For a file with only a single name, the link count is 1.  If it has multiple links, it is reflected here; so you can tell if a file has multiple links, but none are *the one true link*.   Also, note that directory trees are fundamentally constructed via links, so directories typically have a link count of 2 or greaterq.

Comment: Agree, we can find a link count using nlink. And a file itself in unit-based systems is a hard link.

Answer (score 1):

> If two paths have the same inode number; one of them is a hard link.

[A file name is a hard link by definition in Unix/Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filename#Number_of_names_per_file). You cannot distinguish between hard links apart from their paths.